# What is the wavefront quality of VCSELs? How does the wavefront quality of VCSELs compare to Fabry-Perot laser diodes and DPSS lasers?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser, electronics, electrical-engineering, photonics

I am currently looking at [this](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=L795VH1) VCSEL. According to the datasheet, it has a narrow spectral linewidth and emits a Gaussian beam, which are both properties that I find interesting. But I'm also interested in the wavefront quality. However, despite my research, I cannot find any sources that discuss the wavefront quality of VCSELs. What is the wavefront quality of VCSELs? How does the wavefront quality of VCSELs compare to Fabry-Perot laser diodes and DPSS lasers?

Answer (score 3):

Companies that sell optical components often help customers choose the best component. This includes understanding them, how they work, tradeoffs, and so on. Your link has a Complete Product Details button, which has a tech support link. Use it.

Also a good general source for information on optical components is the [RP Photonics Encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html) and [Buyer's Guide](https://www.rp-photonics.com/buyersguide.html). For example, see [Vertical Cavity Surface-emitting Lasers](https://www.rp-photonics.com/vertical_cavity_surface_emitting_lasers.html) and [Fabry–Perot Laser Diodes](https://www.rp-photonics.com/fabry_perot_laser_diodes.html).

Comment: I am aware of this. I have asked Thorlabs, but they do not know what the wavefront quality for that particular diode is. Therefore, I am asking here to get a rough idea of the *general* wavefront quality of VCSELs. I have done my own research on this, but I have not been able to find anything, so I was curious if the more knowledgeable people would know anything (or have any references that explore this).